# What about this picture of André Weil?

Tags: ho.history-overview

Some days ago I came across the following photo of  [André Weil](http://web.archive.org/web/20061126173439im_/http://seven.ihes.fr/IHES/Scientifique/weil/weil-web2.jpg). I obtained it from the archived page [COLLOQUE ANDRÉ WEIL (resume)](http://web.archive.org/web/20061126192137/http://seven.ihes.fr/IHES/Scientifique/weil/resume.html).

Furthermore, I found that this photo was used as the cover of a bibliography of André Weil published by *Maruzen*. Here is one link:

[アンドレ・ヴェイユ自伝・上](https://www.maruzen-publishing.co.jp/item/b294346.html)

I have no Japanese and the above information is useless for me.

Does someone know the history of this photo? Where can it be obtained with higher resolution?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I asked at that site, but I think that here are more expert mathematicians (that know more about the history of mathematics than historicians of science in general) that could know something about this picture. I deleted the post at HSM site yesterday @YemonChoi

Comment: According to a well-known translation service, "Autobiography of André Veil, a mathematician of the 20th century. This book is a valuable photograph discovered after Veil wrote this autobiography and passed away, a memorandum by a Japanese mathematician (Masayoshi Miyanaga, Ichiro Sakura) who had an exchange with Veil, a visit to Veil's apartment by translator Inaba Nobuko New edition which compiled and edited." Based on the background (you can see the Panthéon I think) I'd say the image was taken somewhere in Paris, perhaps at the ENS, maybe at the IHP... Hard to say.

Comment: Or maybe it was even in Weil's apartment as it says in the short text. I don't know if he lived around there. (Today a mathematician's salary is certainly not enough to get an apartment with a patio in this area, but 80 years ago...)

Comment: I translated too, but the description of the book has no information about the photo of the cover. I put the link since I hope that someone has a copy of this book or had read it. I saw that the book has a "photo gallery" and I don't know if the cover is in the photo gallery @NajibIdrissi

Comment: The photo appears in the first page of the *œuvres scientifiques* (collected works) of Weil, volume II (Springer), with the mention "Paris 1953". I didn't find any other mention of the photo in that book.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @abx. In the edition of 1979 the photo is acredited to Lucien Gillet, with the same description "Paris 1953". I don't find more information in the volumes.